# Can't use other commands with default profile in chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When I load a default profile in chromedriver I can't use the other auto commands, it shows this error messsage:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/my_name/.config/google-chrome/") 
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/my_name/Desktop/bot_amazon/chromedriver', options=options)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: i whant to try to make an autologin, but whit default profile doesn't work, alternatively can I only load cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about other commands, you cannot use a namel profile in automation when you already opened Chrome with that profile.

So, close all Chrome instances before running the script. Close *all* browsers (even if you have opened them manually).

Second option is to copy the default directory into another folder, say profile 1, and use that for your automation.

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign